# Transfer data between a mono project and a c++ console app?

Tags: c++, mono, data-transfer

I have a c# (win form) visual studio project which i am now compiling using mono on Linux and i have a c++ application . I want to transfer some data between these two applications , what are my options ?

Comment: Your options are pipes, sockets, shared memory... and many many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Some of them are:

- standard files (with [lockfile](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_lockfile.htm))
- [fifo files](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl4_fifo.htm)
- [socket connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)
- [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)

Depends on what you need, how big is the data, how often you'll exchange information, etc.

Most probably, you'll use a socket connection.

---

Basically, what you need is **IPC (inter-process communication)**. Read more about it, for example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: The data is not transfered continuously , it is some 100-200 numbers which will be transfered very rarely . What might be the easiest to implement in this case ?

Comment: Read about the different ways and pick one. It's very specific. I can't tell you which one is the best for you, without knowing the whole logic of the two programs.

Comment: Ohk , but i can't seem to understand why the logic might be useful as i already said that it is a list of numbers which will be transfered on a button press(or some event which will not occur frequently )

Comment: @rajat - Will the two processes run always on the same machine?

Comment: yes , they will run on same machine and in the same user account always .

Comment: @rajat - well, then you may use named pipes (a.k.a. fifo files). For example, open 2 fifo-s for the both directions. For fifo1 - the one process is reader, the other - writer; for fifo2 - the opposite. NOTE that this is OS specific.